# While creating private pool WinBioOpenSession() is failing and returning WINBIO_E_CONFIGURATION_FAILURE

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm creating a bio metric project in visual studio 2008 using mfc application in VC++ I'm getting following difficulties. Please Help
I'm trying to create private pool using the WinBioOpenSession() method but the function returning WINBIO_E_CONFIGURATION_FAILURE what should I do?

```
BOOL CPrivatePoolBioDlg::EnrollFingerprint()
{
    WINBIO_UNIT_SCHEMA *unitSchemaArray = NULL;
    SIZE_T unitSchemaCount = 0;

    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitIdArray[1]={};
    SIZE_T unitIdCount = ARRAYSIZE(unitIdArray);

    WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle;

    HRESULT hr; // = S_OK;

   //Enumarating devices...
   hr = WinBioEnumBiometricUnits(WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,&unitSchemaArray,&unitSchemaCount);

   if(FAILED(hr))
   {
        CString m;
        m.Format(_T("Unable to Enumarate Device 0x%08x"),hr);
        AfxMessageBox(m);
        return 0;
   }
   //Enumaration Success...
   unitIdArray[0] = unitSchemaArray[0].UnitId;

   //Opening the session...
   hr = WinBioOpenSession(WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,WINBIO_POOL_PRIVATE,WINBIO_FLAG_BASIC,            
                unitIdArray,unitIdCount,&PRIVATE_POOL_DATABASE_ID,&sessionHandle);
   if(FAILED(hr))
   {
    ///////////////////////HERE FUNCTION IS RETURNING WINBIO_E_CONFIGURATION_FAILURE////////////////////
        CString m;
        m.Format(_T("Unable to Start session 0x%08x, %d"),hr, GetLastError());
        AfxMessageBox(m);
        return 0;
   }

   //Session opened...
   WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm Using only one bio metric device SecuGen.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be bioinformatics. I suggest you remove the tag

Comment: I removed the tag but sir I didn't get any help @nbryans

Comment: Where is the code that performs the [Private Pool Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh697323.aspx)?

Comment: @IInspectable Sir I used the same files and setup from msdn that is I used Targetver.h, Stdafx.h, PrivatePoolCommonDefs.h, PrivatePoolSetup.cpp to setup but still getting same result

Comment: I'm calling onInstall() and onAdd() methods before executing WinBioOpenSession() method @IInspectable

Comment: Don't explain, what (you think) your code does. Show your code instead. Make it a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable Sir I found pool configuration was wrong but using your suggestion [Private Pool Setup] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh697323.aspx) I did it. So now it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Before Opening session you should configure **GUID** database into registry and to configure follow the steps on.
- [MSDN Private Pool Helper Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh697321(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MSDN Private Pool Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh697323(v=vs.85).aspx). Before opening session call the methods **OnInstall()** to create configuration and **OnAdd()** to add sensor to private pool from **PrivatePoolSetup.cpp**.
- You should have following files in your project.
- PrivatePoolCommonDefs.h
- PrivatePoolSetup.cpp
- BioHelper.h
- Config.cpp
- Display.cpp

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you were: always getting configuration failure. I did `onInstall` and `onAdd`. I'm calling `WinBioOpenSession` the same way as in your question. If I use System instead Private for the pool, it works. Can you help me?